# assigning every Nth element in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I want to set every Nth element in a list to something else.

(Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994140/how-do-you-make-every-other-integer-in-an-array-equal-to-0-in-matlab?rq=1) which is for Matlab.)

Here's an attempt with N=2:

```
>>> x=['#%d' % i for i in range(10)]
>>> x
['#0', '#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6', '#7', '#8', '#9']
>>> x[0::2] = 'Hey!'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 4 to extended slice of size 5
```

How can I fix this? Slicing seems to expect an iterable, not just a single value.

Comment: This isn't an array, it's a list.  That matters, because there is an array type in the standard library, as well as a different one in the common library `numpy`, and with a numpy `array`, `x[::2] = 'Hey!'` would actually have worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible with list comprehension:

```
x=['#%d' % i for i in range(10)]
['Hey!' if i%3 == 0 else b for  i,b in enumerate(x)]
```

This is appearently with n=3.

Answer (score 5):

The right side of a slice assignment has to be a sequence of an appropriate length; Python is treating `'Hey!'` as a sequence of the characters `'H', 'e', 'y', '!'`.

You can be clever and create a sequence of the appropriate length:

```
x[::2] = ['Hey!'] * len(x[::2])
```

However, the clearest way to do this is a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
    x[i] = 'Hey!'
```

Comment: @JasonS there is a one-liner (added above) but it's significantly less readable.

Comment: I think the first solution is quite Pythonic, personally.